# Require.js#require failing locally (file:///)

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Given the following document, Require.js **functions fine if I run it on a webserver but fails if I open the same document locally (file:///)**.

I'll see 'called' printed to the console when I open the document locally (thus callback fired w/o issue) but:

- **There is no request listed in Firebug's/Chrome's network tab.**
- The variables in common.js aren't defined and none of the console.log statements run.

Require.js is NOT requesting the common.js file when the document is loaded from my desktop.

---

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/<MYBUCKET>/scripts/require.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            require.config({
                baseURL: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<MYBUCKET>'
            });
            require(['scripts/common'], function(){
                console.log('called')
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Given that baseurl states the http/s protocal, I don't understand why this is failing when the document is located on my desktop and works fine when the document is located at http://whatever.com.**

---

Secondary/related:

Ideally I'd like to omit the protocals and allow the browser to handle that itself but this of course also fails completely locally.

***(same code as above, sans http/https)***

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//s3.amazonaws.com/<MYBUCKET>/scripts/require.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            require.config({
                baseURL: '//s3.amazonaws.com/<MYBUCKET>'
            });
            require(['scripts/common'], function(){
                console.log('called')
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

This probably has nothing to do with Require.js and everything to do with how browsers handle requests from file:

Is there a sensible way to make this work regardless of the document's location?

Comment: how do you know that "the variables in common.js aren't defined"?

Comment: Because calling them in the console results in undefined. The common.js file is never requested/loaded/anything.

Comment: but you can't normally call commonJS variable in the console, and that callback should not fire without loading the script... in the show code, all you log is a string literal, and you don't have a formal param on the callback...

Comment: What? No. If common.js defines var x = 99; you can most definitely call x in the console. These are not scoped/curried variables contained in an anonymous functions. I CAN call my variables fine when I load the document from a web server. The only time it doesn't work, thus no net requests in chrome/firebug, is when I load the document from my hdd. Hence the mention of file:///

Comment: Ah, I assume your were assuming I was structuring my code in AMD format. I've been writing code under the old stick everything under a global (or an anonymous function if small enough). AMD is a new concept to me.

Comment: @ChrisCummings I didn't downvote. What exactly do you mean by 'Wikipedia purist'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `baseUrl`, with only the `U` in capitals. You're using `baseURL` which is ignored.

Comment: F me for copy pasting from the web. Right you are!